# How to perform dijit optimization with r.js?

Tags: dojo, r.js

How do we get around the "document is not defined" error when doing a r.js build via r.js -o against a dijit?

Specifically, I'm trying to build r-build.js:

```
define(["require", "exports", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function (require, exports, ContentPane) {
    function simple() {
        return ContentPane;
    }
    return simple;
});
```

Using `r.js.cmd -o r-build.js` and it reports:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
In module tree:
    test/simple
      dijit/layout/ContentPane
        dijit/_Widget
          dojo/query
            dojo/selector/_loader
```

My r-build.js file looks like this:

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "amd",
    dir: "../../release",
    optimize: "none",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "test/simple",
            exclude: ["jquery", "dojo"]
        }
    ],
    packages: [
            {
                name: 'cm',
                location: 'http://localhost:93/CodeMirror'
            },
            {
                name: 'jquery',
                location: 'd:/code/jquery/src',
                main: 'jquery'
            },
            {
                name: 'jquery/ui',
                location: 'http://localhost:93/jquery-ui/ui'
            },
            {
                name: 'jquery/themes',
                location: 'http://localhost:93/jquery-ui/themes'
            },
            {
                name: 'sizzle',
                location: 'http://localhost:93/jquery/external/sizzle/dist',
                main: 'sizzle'
            },
            {
                name: 'dojo',
                location: 'd:/code/dojo'
            },
            {
                name: 'dijit',
                location: 'd:/code/dijit'
            },
            {
                name: 'xstyle',
                location: 'http://localhost:93/xstyle'
            }
    ]
})
```

Comment: After looking more closely I see that query.js references selector/_loader as a plugin ("./selector/_loader!default").

Comment: From http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html, Note: the plugin and its dependencies should be able to run in non-browser environments.  Apparently this dojo plugin cannot.

Comment: Seems to go on...resolve this and hit dojo/i18n...guess r.js can't optimize dojo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fighting with the same issue. Building a r.js bundle with Dojo is a pain. 
That one can be easy to fix... If you don't have problems with the supported browsers (post pre-ie9, for instance) override that file and change the lines that check the querySelectorAll to true and you will not need to do those checks. Like...

```
  has.add("dom-qsa2.1", true);
  has.add("dom-qsa3", true);
```

Hope it helps a bit...